# Setting up Server Side for Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, server-side, google-cloud-messaging

I've recently been learning Android Development and I am trying to make a sample application which uses Google Cloud Messaging. My goal is to make a simple application which can receive Push notifications from a server. I've gotten the client side of the application to work by registering my device. Now I am trying to create the server side. However, I have absolutely no experience in setting up a server or programming on the server side. So I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction so that I could have a server sending the Push notifications. I have been following the tutorial on [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) but I am stuck at the server implementation. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Actually is more easier using Tomcat or AppEngine. [See this tutorial in how to setup your GCM Server.](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)

You need the device registration id to which you want to send the message on the server side you will need your API key, this is a JSP example :

http://yourdomain.com:8080/sendMessage.jsp?registrationID=kSADAS3242&messageToSend=Hello

```
String value = request.request.getParameter("messageToSend");
String registrationId = request.getParameter("registrationID");
Sender sender = new Sender("YOUR API KEY");
Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("FLAG","SERVE").addData("MSG", value).build();
Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
```

On your client device should expect :

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Got a message from Google Cloud Messaging !!");
    String tag = intent.getExtras().getString("FLAG");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("MSG");
    Log.i(TAG, tag + " : " + message);
}
```

This should print "SERVE : Hello"

Comment: What API are you using? Because I think the way you implement the server is no longer supported by ADT.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used PHP you should be familiar with xampp or similar software.

If not, all you have to do is download and install it, start the services and on your browser go to:

```
http://localhost/xampp
```

to test if it's properly installed.

If you can see the Xampp page you can start running scripts php from xampp/htdocs and run them like this:

```
http://localhost/yourscript.php
```

Try a simple hello world:

```
<?php 

echo 'hello world';

?>
```

After that you should be ready to start following [this tutorial](http://distriqt.com/post/1273) or any tutorial in google just typing [gcm php tutorial](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&client=ubuntu&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&client=ubuntu&sclient=psy-ab&q=gcm%20php%20tutorial&oq=gcm%20php%20tutorial&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i5i10i30.1154.2932.0.3077.9.9.0.0.0.0.93.490.9.9.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.JPERCIwAjeM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cd9f47492dab50a6&biw=1477&bih=745&ion=1)

I found that php is the most simple way for me to configure the server side for GCM, hope you find it useful...